# Integrating the logarithm of a function including a square root of a second degree polynomial

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

I have been trying for some time to calculate the following integral:
$$\int \ln\left(k+\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}\right)\ dx$$
where k, a, b and c are real numbers.
I have tried several strategies, but without success. For example, the latest try used the fact that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\cdot \left(k+\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}\right)\right)=\ln\left(k+\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}\right)+\frac{x(b+2ax)}{2(k+\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c})\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$$
Hence
$$\int \ln(k+\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}) dx=x \ln(k+\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c})-\int \frac{x(b+2ax)}{2(k+\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c})\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$$
but then I run into trouble with the integral of the last term.
Any ideas?

Comment: The standard method for solving integrals involving square-root terms with quadratic radicands is [Euler's substitutions][1]. As you might expect, there's really no avoiding a minimum amount of casework unless the ranges of values of taken by the parameters are suitably restricted ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln%28k+%2B+sqrt%28a*x%5E2+%2B+b*x+%2Bc%29%29

(Select the whole link; for some reason a part of it isn't part of the active link.)

One look at the answer Wolfram Alpha gives you, tells you that there is a lot more to this integral than meets the eye... The main problem with your latest method, is the fact that the integral you get while trying to solve it using integration by parts method has too large a denominator for practical human computation/evaluation.

The only idea I can give you, is to try solving smaller cases of this integral (Some examples, like giving values to your constants...Or making the quadratic a linear...Or removing the constant k), & see where that takes you. This way, you get an idea of what needs to be done for solving the original one.

Still, unlikely that this can be solved without computer aid. Where did you come across this? It's a good question!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. I came across that function when working on a problem of mutual impedance. The only way ahead I found was to break the problem in several cases. Couldn't solve the integral analytically.

Comment: Are you an electrical engineer? And did breaking the problem into several cases help? If it did, please post it as an answer; will be very useful for me and others alike, who've no idea how exactly one can solve this question.

Comment: If possible, could you also link me to a source where mutual impedance problems are there? I would like to solve some; I''m pretty sure I can;t solve any without help though...